# If Stormbreaker is a ‘King’s Weapon’ why didn’t Odin have it?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, odin

I am wondering why Odin didn’t have Stormbreaker since it is a ‘King’s Weapon’, or was the magical staff/spear that he carried around in the *Thor* movies more powerful than Stormbreaker?

Comment: Because he had a few of his own. Besides, Stormbreaker wasn't made yet.

Comment: @Mooz, so Odin and Thor were unaware that Stormbreaker could be created and be more powerful than their current weapons?

Comment: There's no definitive comparison between Stormbreaker and Gungnir afaik, just that Stormbreaker is "meant to be the greatest", but designs don't always pan out in reality. But since it's the dwarves' job to invent and design, yeah it's pretty likely that they would come up with improved designs all the time, wouldn't you think?

Comment: @DariM, I agree that they would come up with improved designs, I am mostly curious as to why it hadn’t already been built.

Comment: This isn't me being sarcastic - just an attempt at humour. Imagine if the Dwarves sent word that they had a new iPhone every few decades. You might decide to skip one or two upgrades, or consider whether you need a new one when your old one is working perfectly fine. Besides, it's not like they have a prototype anyway, and maybe they're not going to spend Uru on prototyping every design they can think of without some funding or backing, cause they'll come up with a better one soon, maybe.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons really for why he didn't want it.

#### It was symbolic

Gungnir was symbolic of the campaign that Odin led to Conquer the Nine Realms because it was his weapon during it. He's then used it to maintain the peace and to lead afterwards. This was a symbol of power for Asgard so it makes sense he'd then keep using it even just for his largely ceremonial role nowadays as Thor is doing a lot of the fighting.

[image: Mural seen on the Throne Room's ceiling with Odin wielding Gungir at the end of the campaign]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### It appears to be tradition to use your "own" weapon

During Thor's ceremony Odin says the below which indicates somewhat that keeping the one weapon during your rule is somewhat of a tradition. Thor would never have gotten Stormbreaker if Mjolnir wasn't destroyed so that backs up the theory that they keep their one weapon usually.

> **Odin:** And though the day has come for **a new King to wield his own weapon** -- that duty remains the same. Thor Odinson, my heir, my first-born. So long entrusted with this mighty hammer, Mjolnir. Forged in the heart of a dying star, from the sacred metal of Uru. Only one may lift it. Only one is worthy. Who wields this hammer commands the lightning and the storm. Its power has no equal -- as a weapon, to destroy, or as a tool, to build. **It is a fit companion for a King.**
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

#### He didn't need it

Gungnir is clearly a powerful weapon, we get a glimpse of Bor using it at the beginning of *Thor: The Dark World* where he defeats the Dark Elves. It's power is then seen several times afterwards with Loki using it a bit too. He managed to defend Asgard and the Nine Realms with it so he clearly didn't really need a new one.

> **Odin:** Gungnir. Its aim is true, its power strong. With it I have defended Asgard and the lives of the innocent across the Nine Realms since the time of the Great Beginning.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Gungnir can even open the Bifrost as we see in *Thor* when Odin banishes Thor. He might have to use it more as a key than being able to summon the Bifrost like Stormbreaker can but Odin didn't really venture out anymore. He didn't have much need for summoning the Bifrost on the fly so the upgrade wasn't worth it. Presumably though Gungnir could summon the Bifrost like we saw Heimdall do with the broken Hofund at the start of *Avengers: Infinity War* it just takes a bit more.

#### Your familiarity with a weapon matters

It may be obvious to some but familiarity with a specific weapon matters a lot and even more so when switching between types of weapons. Gungnir is a staff/spear with a ranged attack whereas Stormbreaker is a big old axe. They require vastly different fighting techniques which Odin might not have been comfortable with so wouldn't have wanted it.

We see this somewhat in the duel Thor has with Hela whilst wielding Gungnir, he is easily bested. In part this is due to him not awakening his power and Hela being super strong but he was also unfamiliar with Gungnir being mainly a hammer user until then. He didn't use Gungnir effectively because he was unfamiliar with it.

#### Stormbreaker wasn't created yet

Lastly, and it's quite important, Stormbreaker wasn't created yet and the theory on the weapon wasn't even completed. Eitri states *"In theory, it could even summon the Bifrost."* meaning it was probably still in the prototype stage. If that wasn't completed and the weapon wasn't even built it makes sense why Odin wouldn't use it.